# useDataProvider hook for custom methods

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin

I call `const dataProvider = useDataProvider()` in my component and can use the default methods like `dataProvider.getList("resource",{})` without any issue. Then, I expanded my `DataProvider` with a custom `get` method for retrieving objects that don't have the required `Record` structure like the following:

```
  get: async <T = any>(
    resource: string,
    params: Partial<QueryParams>
  ): Promise<{
    data: T
  }> => {
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(params)}`

    return httpClient(url)
      .then(({ json }) => ({
        data: json,
      }))
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
        return Promise.reject(e)
      })
  },
```

I can use this method without any problem when I import the `DataProvider` object directly, but when I want to use it with the `useDataProvider` hook I get the following typing message:
`(...a: unknown[]) => unknown`

What do I have to add/change, so that my custom data provider methods also have proper typing for the `useDataProvider` hook?

I am using `react-admin` version 3.14, and probably soon upgrade to 4.x.

Comment: Could you please reproduce minimal code here https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-forked-46jcsb?file=/src/index.ts ?

Comment: I tried, but the sandbox breaks when I want to include the `Admin` component of react-admin. I wanted to glue everything together like this: `function App() {
  return (
    <Admin dataProvider={customDataProvider}>
    
    </Admin>
  )
};` but it throws an error for invalid regex, which is ridiculous: /src/index.ts: Unterminated regular expression (88:9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were multiple things to add here:
First, create a custom DataProvider type like this.

```js
type CustomDataProvider = DataProvider & {
  get: <ResponseType = any>(
    resource: string,
    params: Partial<QueryParams>
  ) => Promise<{
    data: ResponseType
  }>
}
```

Second, create a custom DataProviderProxy type.

```js
type CustomDataProviderProxy = DataProviderProxy & {
  get: <ResponseType = any>(
    resource: string,
    params: Partial<QueryParams>,
    options?: UseDataProviderOptions
  ) => Promise<{
    data: ResponseType
  }>
}
```

Third, use it in the `useDataProvider` hook as type parameters.

```js
export function useCustomDataProvider() {
  return useDataProvider<CustomDataProvider, CustomDataProviderProxy>()
}
```

This allows the proper use of typed responses in the components:

```js
  const dataProvider = useCustomDataProvider()
  dataProvider.get<User>('user', {}).then(({ data }) => console.log(data.id))
```

Thanks to @FatihAziz for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: @FatihAziz Thank you! It's a really nice solution I think. Maybe you also know the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74279124/usequerywithstore-works-but-usegetlist-does-not

Answer (score 1):

Because of lack of additional information,

I assume the `get` method is reserved, thus you can't change the type.

Instead, you can change `get` to `getPartial`, like:

```js
getPartial: async <T = any>(
    resource: string,
    params: Partial<QueryParams>
  ): Promise<{
    data: T
  }> => {
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(params)}`

    return httpClient(url)
      .then(({ json }) => ({
        data: json,
      }))
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
        return Promise.reject(e)
      })
  },
```

But if it's turnout `get` is not reserved by `react-admin` you can use type casting instead.

I have created the code example with type casting here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-forked-46jcsb?file=/src/index.ts

I hope it helps,

Comment: I don't think the `get` method is reserved. When I extended the `DataProvider` interface with your suggested `getPartial` method it does somewhat work, but not properly. Using the `useDataProvider` hook of type `CustomDataProvider` does not let me type the `getPartial` method because its signature is: `(property) getPartial: (resource: string, params: Partial<QueryParams>, options?: UseDataProviderOptions) => Promise<{
    data: unknown;
}>`