# UseQueryWithStore works but useGetList does not

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin

I have a component that fetches a list of items from the data provider like this:

```js
  const { data, total, loading, loaded, error, refetch } = useQueryWithStore({
    type: 'getList',
    resource: 'client/account',
    payload: {
      pagination: {
        page: page + 1,
        perPage: rowsPerPage,
      },
      sort: {
        order: sortOrder,
        field: sortBy,
      },
    },
  })

  if (!loaded) {
    return <Loading />
  }
  if (error) {
    return <p>ERROR</p>
  }
 // render data
```

Everything works and I can render the list of data in a table.

Now, I wanted to use `useGetList` specialized hook with this code:

```js
 const { data, total, ids, loading, loaded, error, refetch } = useGetList<ClientAccount>(
    'client/account',
    {
      page: page + 1,
      perPage: rowsPerPage,
    },
    {
      order: sortOrder,
      field: sortBy,
    }
  )

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />
  }
  if (error) {
    return <p>ERROR</p>
  }
// render
```

It successfully calls the data provider as it would with `useQueryWithStore`, it gets the data back from the API, but then all the fields just do not get the fetched data:

- `total` is undefined
- `data` is an empty object
- `ids` is an empty list
- `loaded` is true
- `loading` is false

I'm using react-admin version 3.14.

What do I do wrong? Should this behave similarly?

Edit:
When I inspect the redux actions in Redux DevTools I can see that everything worked properly. It dispatched the following actions:

- CUSTOM_QUERY
- CUSTOM_QUERY_LOADING
- RA/FETCH_START
- CUSTOM_QUERY_SUCCESS
- RA/FETCH_END

And for the CUSTOM_QUERY_SUCCESS I see the following output:
{"type":"GET_LIST","resource":"client/account","payload":{"pagination":{"page":1,"perPage":20},"sort":{"order":"desc","field":"id"},"filter":{}}}(pin):{data:[{id:'e57…1987}
But still, I don't get any data in the destructuring of the `useGetList` hook.

Edit2:
When debugging the code I see that it uses the `useGetList` from `node_modules/ra-core/esm/dataProvider/useGetList.js`, but I also see an implementation in `node_modules/ra-core/ra-core/dataProvider/useGetList.ts`. What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useGetList` needs a registered `Resource` in order to work properly while `useQueryWithStore` doesn't. Adding it resolved the issue.

Comment: great! you find the solution. i already make a draft but i didnt send it... lmao